# Google Map doesn't loads properly in ligh box pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two textbox in which we can enter locations & on button click route between two points shows in the map. Problem is on page it shows properly but when I use lighbox popup then map only shows grey color like below image. For pop up box I have used asp.net control modalpopupextender.

[image]

JS Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var source, destination;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
            new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
        });

        function GetRoute() {
            debugger;
            var mumbai = new google.maps.LatLng(18.9750, 72.8258);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: mumbai
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

            //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
            source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
            destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

            var request = {
                origin: source,
                destination: destination,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });

            //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            service.getDistanceMatrix({
                origins: [source],
                destinations: [destination],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                    var distance2 = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text; /*used for ID firstNumber*/
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                    var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
                    var dvDuration = document.getElementById("dvDuration");
                    var dvDurationC = document.getElementById("dvDurationC")
                    dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                    dvDistance.value = parseFloat(distance);
                    firstNumber.innerHTML = distance2 /*used for ID firstNumber*/
                    dvDuration.innerHTML = duration;
                } else {
                    alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making these two changes:

- Remove the display property and set visibility: hidden on #map.
- Move #map to a place where the space it inhabits won’t be noticed. Right before  is probably a good choice.

Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.matthewgifford.com/blog/2012/10/16/google-map-in-a-lightbox/).